# Help with Synaptiks touchpad

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics

I bought a laptop 2 weeks ago, wiped Windows8 off and installed Ubuntu 12.04.
I've been trying to install synaptiks for the past 6 days trying multiple fix's, so I could configure my touchpad because the touchpad hits my left palm when I type and consistently erases most things because of it and I cant 2 finger vert scroll.

I believed the problem was related to my touchpad driver but I had the its-saucy synaptics installed for everything. When I use xlist it shows my touchpad is identified yet when I run synaptiks it says it can't find a touchpad. Any help greatly appreciated.

The internal error I have is:
ExecutablePath: usr/bin/synaptiks

Package: kde-config-touchpad 0.8.1-1ubuntu1.2

ProblemType: Crash

Title:
synaptiks crashed with AttributeError in show_configuration_dialog():'SynaptiksNotifierItem'object has no attribute 'touchpad'

Traceback:
File"usr/lib/python2,7/dist-packages/synaptiks/kde/trayapplication.py",line 260, in newInstance self.icon.show_configuration_dialog()

File"usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/synaptiks/kde/trayapplication.py",line 241, in show_configuration_dialogself.touchpad, self.touchpad_manager,self_config)

Attribute error:'SynaptiksNotifierItem' object has no attribute 'touchpad'

ApportVersion: 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.6

Architecture: amd64

distro: Ubuntu 12.04

if there's any directory spelling mistakes it's because I typed it all out

Answer (score 0):

**1.****Enabling two finger scroll:**

Go to **Mouse and Touchpad** in **System Settings**. There you can find
Two Finger Scroll under **Touchpad** tab. I hope this solves your problem.

**2.****Enable/disable Touchpad**

This is not an exact solution. But it might solve the issue. You can write a bash script to toggle the touchpad on/off. And give a keyboard shortcut for this script to run.

- Step 1:

  Open terminal. (press **ctrl+alt+t**)
- Step 2:

  Type **gedit touchpad** and press enter.
- Step 3:

  Copy the following script.

  *SYNSTATE=$(xinput list-props "**XXX**" | grep Enabled | grep -Eo     '.$')
  if [ $SYNSTATE = 0 ]; then xinput set-prop "**XXX**" "Device    Enabled" 1
  else xinput set-prop "**XXX**" "Device Enabled" 0; fi*

  Replace **XXX** with the name of the touchpad.

  To find out the name of the touchpad just execute command **"xinput list"** in the terminal.

  Save the document.
- Step 4:

  Now execute the following commands one by one.

  **chmod +x touchpad**

  **sudo mv touchpad /bin/**
- Step 5:

  Done!!! You can now enable/disable the touchpad just by executing **"touchpad"** command in the terminal.
- Step 6:

  To add keyboard shortcut for enabling and disabling touchpad, open **Keyboard** in **System Settings**. Under **Shortcuts** tab, select **Custom Shortcuts** and add command  **"touchpad"** to the list. Assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: in my mouse controls it doesn't have a touchpad tab